# My stores - postal code search

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop store and on the page of my stores - stores where the client can buy my products I have a search box. The client can search near stores by city name, postal code or direction.

When I search some store by city name it works perfectly , but when I do it by postal code, some stores are displayed and some are not.

Has anybody had this problem? How can I solve it?
**Note all the stores are configured the same -so there cannot be a problem of configuration of the module (store locator).
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If your website use the stores controller of prestashop, this can help :

First check if you have a Google Maps API key for your website.

Second check the value of "radius" input field (can be hidden).

You can analyse your queryanswer like this :

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/?controller=stores&ajax=1&latitude=45.8191313&longitude=4.37707039999998&radius=100
```

when you change the value of radius your find more and more stores. so check if you see all your stores and determines the good radius for your input.
if the stores is not in the list, verify your data.
Hope it helps